# How to create a docker config file

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I need to create a docker config file so that I don't need to keep passing the reference to it via [terminal with --config-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

I have [read here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/config_create/)

But following the advice I get:

```
$ docker config create /home/hutber/.docker/.config
"docker config create" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker config create --help'.

Usage:  docker config create [OPTIONS] CONFIG file|-

Create a configuration file from a file or STDIN as content
```

Comment: turns out in linux, as per the docs, the default location is `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. This solved my problem